# Have Excel Check Cell format at every Change

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, cell

I have a VBA code that helps users schedule projects by entering either a date or days until completion for particular tasks and then creates a graph that shows the percent completion of the project.

The VBA code hinges on the formatting of the cell to perform its calculations. Excel does a great job of choosing a number or date correctly the first time a user inputs a value. However if a user was to input a date and then decide to input a number (ex: 7) they would end up with  1/7/1900 as the date, which then makes excel perform the VBA incorrectly.

Is there a way to get Excel to "reconsider" the formatting of the cell each time it is changed? If not is there a way to force it to do so in VBA and choose either number or date formatting only?

Thanks,

-MK

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

1. as a user prefixing an "=" is probably your best bet.
2. Adding "e0" on the end will format as an ugly scientific number, but at least it's accurately represented in memory.
3. Another option is multiplying by 100 followed by a "%".

You've accurately noticed that [dates to numbers](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8) don't change back as easily. On the other hand any entry with a front-slash '/' seems to format as a date pretty reliably. The single apostrophe ' formats as Text, which is not very good for automated solutions. A number by itself is too general to change the NumberFormat, so any "automatic" solution would be non-standard.